# Whats causing this artefacts?

Tags: three.js, webgl

I'm trying to map a 3D Texture to a Voxel Terrain, the pixel color from the texture should align with the terrain geometry and I don't want any gradients.

It's kinda working but depending on the camera angle I can see artefacts and I would like to know what's causing this and how to fix it.

Is it some kind of bleeding? I've already tried to change my texture as described here: 
[ogr3d tilemap](http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=61602) but without success.

I think it's not a mipmapping bug because I turned it off and if I turn it on it looks way worse.

The geometry is grid aligned.
I set min and mag filtering to nearest and wrapping to clampToEdge.

fragment:

```
vec2 computeSliceOffset(float slice, float slicesPerRow, vec2 sliceSize) {
  return sliceSize * vec2(mod(slice, slicesPerRow), floor(slice / slicesPerRow));   
}

vec4 sampleAs3DTexture(sampler2D tex, vec3 texCoord, float size, float numRows, float slicesPerRow) {    
  float slice   = texCoord.z * size;                                                
  float sliceZ  = floor(slice);                                                     
  float zOffset = fract(slice);                                                     

  vec2 sliceSize = vec2(1.0 / slicesPerRow, 1.0 / numRows);
  vec2 sliceOffset = computeSliceOffset(sliceZ, slicesPerRow, sliceSize);
  vec2 uv = texCoord.xy * sliceSize;                                           
  vec4 sliceColor = texture2D(tex, sliceOffset + uv);                               
  return sliceColor;                                                                
}

vec3 texCoord = mod(worldPosition.xyz,128.0)/128.0;                                 
vec4 myColor = sampleAs3DTexture(texture_0,texCoord,64.0,8.0,8.0);
```

[image: pic]
[image: pic]

Comment: Are you using a voxel engine? Looks to me like its caused by the ambient occlusion calculations.

Comment: 3d textures don't exist in WebGL. They instead have to emulated so it would be helpful for you to show your code since we can't see how you emulated 3D textures

Comment: @WaclawJasper I'm sure it's not AO because I've also other shaders and it works there.

Comment: @gman, I saw your talk about webgl performance that's where I got the idea from but I think I'm missing something because of the flickering.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I added my shader code.

Comment: @coffeecup the problem is likely to be caused by something in the lighting calculations. Try setting `myColor` to a solid color and see if the problem persists.

Comment: I'm only sampling the color from the texture I don't have any light calculations ( except AO ), if I set it to a solid color there are no artefects so I think there is something wrong with the color lookup.